# Orchard 1.8 - How to trigger action when user logs in

Tags: c#, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I created a custom part that I attached to the User part (I need it to store additional data related to the user). I need to execute some code when the user registers the account or each time he authenticates himself using that account.
I put the code to execute during the registration in the handler of my custom part, inside the OnCreated method, but I cannot find how to identify the login operation. Is there a method of the handler where I can put that code that I need to execute on each login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code won't be in the part but in the `IUserEventHandler` LoggedIn event.

So an example implementation would be:

```
public class ModUserEvents : IUserEventHandler {
    public ModUserEvents() {
    }

    public void LoggedIn(IUser user) {
        // go go do your stuff
    }


    #region unused events
    public void Approved(IUser user){
    }

    public void Created(UserContext context){
    }

    public void Creating(UserContext context) {
    }

    public void LoggedOut(IUser user) {
    }

    public void AccessDenied(IUser user) {
    }

    public void ChangedPassword(IUser user) {
    }

    public void SentChallengeEmail(IUser user) {
    }

    public void ConfirmedEmail(IUser user) {
    }
    #endregion
}
```

You'll need to reference Orchard.Users and add `@using Orchard.Users.Events`

Comment: This works if I log from the Orchard UI, but I'm also using an open authentication procedure that explicitly calls the SignIn method of Orchard.Security.IAuthenticationService. With this procedure I have a problem, because the user is correctly logged but the LoggedIn event is not triggered. The procedure is the one in the OpenAuthentication module that I found in the Orchard gallery.

Comment: Call the method explicitly yourself?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the Open Authentication module does not call the LoggedIn event after correctly executing the SignIn. If I add that instruction everything works.